# MongoDB: How to sort providing 2 filters?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a program in which i can get a leaderboard of people with highest levels(descending order) and i am getting it. But the case is that they are not arranged by another factor which is xp( every 100 xp == +1 level)

I tried searching for solutions but sadly couldn't find it, maybe if i could get a head-up through? Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Simply provide two sort fields. `.sort({ xp: -1, level: -1 })`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.